# Type 'Observable<boolean>' is missing

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Why is that whenever I save or control save on the parent component the error occurs and when I save or control save on the child component the error is gone , what causes this issue ?

Type 'Observable' is missing the following properties from type 'Subject': observers, closed, isStopped, hasError, and 6 more.

Article : https://newbedev.com/how-to-reload-or-refresh-only-child-component-in-angular-8

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lFQnR.png)

#html code

```
<app-team-users [selectedNewUser] = "newUsers" [selectedTransactionTeam]="modelForm.value.teams"
                [selectedTransactionUser]="modelForm.value.users" (transactionUserEvent)="transactionUserEvent($event)"
                (transactionTeamEvent)="transactionTeamEvent($event)"
                [resetFormSubject]="resetFormSubject.asObservable()">
            </app-team-users>
```

#ts code of parent component

```
  resetFormSubject: Subject<boolean> = new Subject<boolean>();
```

#child component code which is app-team-users

```
  @Input() resetFormSubject: Subject<boolean> = new Subject<boolean>();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type this tag attempts to make for the variable `resetFormSubject`:

```
[resetFormSubject]="resetFormSubject.asObservable()"
```

is `Observable<boolean>`

while the type of

```
@Input() resetFormSubject: Subject<boolean>
```

is `Subject<boolean>`

Weird things happen when you don't have the types matching...

the solution might be as simple as removing the `.asObservable()`.

Comment: removing from the template ?

Comment: the types need to match. from the parts of the code you shared, that seems to be the place to change